# Voltage Distribution Inside a Cylinder

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, coordinate-systems, bessel-functions

I was assigned this problem, and quite honestly I do not know where to begin.

If I could get some help and an explanation of the Bessel function, also?

Thank you.

[image: homework]

I know my conditions are:
\begin{align}
V(a, z) &= 0\\
V(r, 0) &= 1
\end{align}
$V\to 0$ as $z\to \infty$

Comment: This question is too broad and I suspect is unlikely to get an answer in its current form; can you either isolate a single question that you're stuck on (and preferably write it into the post rather than include an image) to ask out of this, or possibly isolate multiple questions and post them separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that solution is of the form presented, we first need to know what the Laplace equation in cylindrical coordinates is.
$$
\nabla^2u = \frac{1}{r}\partial_r(ru_r) + \frac{1}{r^2}u_{\phi\phi} + u_{zz} = 0
$$
We have no angular dependence so 
$$
\nabla^2u = \frac{1}{r}\partial_r(ru_r) + u_{zz} = 0
$$
Let $u(r,z) = R(r)Z(z)$.
\begin{alignat}{2}
\frac{1}{r}(R'Z + rR''Z) + RZ'' &= \frac{R' + rR''}{rR} + \frac{Z''}{Z}\\
\frac{R' + rR''}{rR} &= -\frac{Z''}{Z} &&{}= -k^2\\
rR'' + R' +rk^2R &=0\tag{1}\\
Z''-k^2Z &=0
\end{alignat}
Therefore, we have $Z\sim\{e^{k z}, e^{-k z}\}$. Since the equation is bounded at infinity, $Z\sim e^{-k z}$. Now let's multiple equation (1) by $r$.
$$
r^2R'' + rR' + r^2k^2 R = 0
$$
which is the Bessel equation of order zero since $m^2 = 0$. The general form of the Bessel equation is
$$
r^2R'' + rR' + (r^2k^2 - m^2) R = 0
$$
Thus, $R(r) = \mathcal{J}_0(k r)$. Then $R(a) = \mathcal{J}_{0n}(k_n a) = 0$. Let $\lambda_n = k_na$ be the zeros of the Bessel equatoin. Then $k_n = \frac{\lambda_n}{a}$.
$$
V(r, z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{0n}\mathcal{J}_{0n}\Bigl(\frac{\lambda_{0n}r}{a}\Bigr)e^{-\frac{\lambda_{0n}z}{a}}
$$

Comment: Ok.
I now have this final solution.
Would you know how to use mathematica to compute the first three numerical solutions?
[equation](http://i.imgur.com/iPnDhxr.png)

Comment: Check out the documentation on BesselJ in Mathematica